# Magento 2 - Search title/product name only

Tags: magento-2.1, search, catalogsearch, search-terms, search-type

**Magento 2.1.2**

We disabled the default Search value (YES/NO) of "Description" and "Short Description" to "NO", we will search only in the **"Product Name"** - but if the Search Keyword is **"live"** it does not find any products, if you use the keyword **"livevest"** it does return products.

**How can I see the results for following example?**

Product Name: **"Red Live*vest* Model 2017"**

Keyword: **"vest"**
OR
Keyword: **"Live"**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you advice  how did you disable description and short description

Comment: Are you using a search plugin? Also, what search are you using? Do you have elasticsearch set up?

Answer (score -2):

Please do indexing of the site.

Go to root folder of magento from CLI and type bellow command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: i try but very bad, this was unfortunately not the solution. Maybe do you have other tips?